# Deploying dynamic libraries: folder structure library placement

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

I want to create a dynamic library A that includes another dynamic library B.
The library A itself is used in a project that creates a GUI that uses A. The Gui application crashes as soon as I click on compile. I  think it is a library import issue.

So I set up a minimal example, that you can find at the end of the question.
In the minimal example, I can get the main project working, but not in the real project. I am missing the analogy.

As I think from the example at the end, it seems to boil down to the placing of the libraries of B in my folder structure. My directory structure is like

```
LibA
     include (include folder for the class "MainUsesLibA"
        libaclass.h
        libbclass.h
        libb.dll (copied from output of LibB compilation)
    LibA.pro
    libaclass.cpp
    main.cpp
LibB
    include
      libaclass.h      
    LibB.pro
    libbclass.cpp
    main.cpp
MainUsesLibA
    libs
        liba.dll
        libaclass.h  <-- you do only need libaclass.h, not libbclass.h
        libb.dll     <-- must be supported, else CRASH **before** compiling! 
                         This was my initial error (*)
```

(*) So, this is the main question: Dynamic libraries must be deployed until the end, even if they are used inside another dll. Clear about that. But with my main AudioPlayer app, I also tried this and first failed (now have to check again after things are more clear to me).

**The question is: To which directory do I have to copy the 'libb.dll' in general so that 'liba.dll' finds it? I do not have to specify 'libb.dll' in the pro-file, but I need to have it in the project directory. Where exactly? Do I know this from the inclusion inside of LibA? Or is it always in the same directory of LibA?**

There is the library "libB" that is used in library "libA" that is used in the main app "MainUsesLibA".

LibB.pro

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = libb
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += TEST_BUILD_LIBB

INCLUDEPATH += \
$$PWD/include

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    libbclass.cpp

HEADERS += \
$$PWD/include/libbclass.h
```

libbclass.h

```
#ifndef LIBBCLASS_H
#define LIBBCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

#if defined TEST_BUILD_LIBB
    #define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
    #define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC LibBClass : public QObject
{
public:
    LibBClass(QObject* parent = 0);
    void sayHello();
};

#endif // LIBBCLASS_H
```

libbclass.cpp

```
#include "libbclass.h"
#include <QDebug>
LibBClass::LibBClass(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent){

}
void LibBClass::sayHello(){
    qDebug()<<"Lib B: Hello";
}
```

The lib "libB" is created and I copy the dll to the include dir of LibA.

LibA.pro

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = liba
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += TEST_BUILD_LIBA

LIBS += -L$$PWD/include/ -lb

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include

SOURCES += \
main.cpp \
libaclass.cpp

HEADERS += \
include/libaclass.h \
include/libbclass.h
```

libaclass.h

```
#ifndef LIBACLASS_H
#define LIBACLASS_H

#include <QObject>

#if defined TEST_BUILD_LIBA
    #define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
    #define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class LibBClass;
class TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC LibAClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LibAClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    void sayHello();
private:
    LibBClass* libB;
};

#endif // LIBACLASS_H
```

libaclass.cpp

```
#include "libaclass.h"
#include "libbclass.h"

#include <QDebug>

LibAClass::LibAClass(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent){
    libB = new LibBClass(this); 
}
void LibAClass::sayHello(){
    qDebug()<<"LibA: Hello";
    libB->sayHello(); 
}
```

MainUsesLibA.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MainUsesLibA
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -la    <-- only specify the library LibA! 
                                 You do not need to specify LibB! (At least for compiling)

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs

SOURCES += \
main.cpp\
mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += \
mainwindow.h \
libs/libaclass.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  You might make that one of your tags.

Comment: You don't have a class named `LibB` .. you have `LibBClass`, you probably meant that.

Comment: Yes I noticed immediatley after writing. On SO i see this, but not the last hour when coding... Well I am editing now to explain my original problem with the import of libA in another project.

Comment: Please, give some clarifications. First, what do you mean by `The Gui application crashes as soon as I click on compile`? Qt Creator crashes or your application has a compile button? Second, does your application run ok if you manually copy all the dll files it depends on to the folder with your exe file?

Comment: It crashes when I click on the green triangle button of Qt Creator. The app is not running then. I meanwhile got it working by copying some of the dlls of the 3rd party lib (e.g. "LibB") and the dll of my own lib ("LibA") to the same folder (no subfolders, as opposed to when I created "LibA") of my GUI app. My question is still there, because how do I know to which folder to copy all the needed dlls? Now in the end, they are in another folder (relative to the executable) than while creating LibA.